# Files share in BlueStacks 4 is not working

Tags: files, bluestacks

I am trying to drop files from my PC into the BlueStacks 4 Android emulator. I put them in: C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks\Engine\UserData\SharedFolder. 
I see some of them in sdcard/DCIM/SharedFolder.

However, I only see three (random?) documents. All the maps are not transferred, all the other documents in those maps are not transferred either.

I have plenty of storage left in BlueStacks.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this!

I had a similar problem. My shared folder is this same thing.
I'm using Bluestacks 4, build 4.180.0.9002 and Windows 10 Ver.1909, build 18363.657.

My media manager open... but I get stuck in a gray screen with no icons at all (it must the main screen of the app)

None os the searches I did worked =(
However found 1 tip that help: a folder named mnt (/ -> mnt) that have a path /sdcard/windows/bstsharedfolder...

I made some tests... I put 1 picture in the C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks\UserData\SharedFolder\ and found it in the bluestacks file search. But when I see the FULL path... Surprise MTF: it was in mnt\windows\bstsharedfolder (NOT IN mnt\sdcard\windows\bstsharedfolder)!

With the app EZ File Explorer I found in this 'mnt' folder, this another WINDOWS folder  (before the sdcard folder of the tip above).
SURPRISE! All the folders (bstsharedfolder, documents, pictures...) was there, WITH MY WINDOWS FILES!
So, all I did was copy and past in this bstsharedfolder. Now C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks\UserData\SharedFolder\ has all my BST files that I need!

Summing up: the 2 folders that share files between BST and Windows are:
Windows: C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks\UserData\SharedFolder\
Bluestacks: mnt\windows\bstsharedfolder

Note: I tried copy to the pictures folder (out: mnt\windows\pictures; in: C:\Users\YourUser\Pictures\BlueStacks) but it asked permitions. So the bstsharedfolder worked with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still struggling with this and needs a quick, non-permanent solution, you can also go into the "Media Manager" application in BlueStacks and select "Import from Windows". That seemed to grab everything and update the media cache without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the sdcard/windows/bstsharedfolder, thats where your files should be,and use the built in Media manager, third party app dont seem to be working.

Comment: The problem is that the built-in Media Manager doesn't actually let you do anything with the files, like move them to where you need them to be... you can only browse and look. Tapping a file tries to open it in another app which, again, will fail because the `/sdcard/windows` folder shows empty to any app but Media Manager. It seems you need a third-party root file explorer and open `/mnt/windows` instead.